# Ubuntu 14.04: Low screen resolution

Tags: intel-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Toshiba DX1210 and have not been able to change the screen resolution from 1280x1024 when the specs say that it supports 1920x1080. I have tried installing the drivers for the Intel HD Graphics 3000 graphics card (v1.0.5 (64bit) from: [01](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads)) which did not have any effect.

I have tried running `xrandr` and adding a new mode but have not been able to get this to work as when I try to switch to the new mode there is an error (I think because it is above the "maximum" of 1280x1024). Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    1280x1024      77.0*
```

I only have the one monitor which has a built in display and am not using any software such as VirtualBox. I had some trouble installing Ubuntu and eventually figured out that the `nomodeset` option needed to be set. I have tried disabling it after installing those drivers but the display did not work (blank screen after the Ubuntu logo when booting) and needed to re-enable it again to log in.

How can I get my system to fully accept the drivers I installed?

Answer (score 0):

Adding undetected resolutions

Due to buggy hardware or drivers, your monitor's correct resolutions may not always be detected. For example, the EDID data block queried from your monitor may be incorrect.

If the mode already exists, but just isn't associated for the particular output, you can add it like this:

```
$ xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600
```

If the mode doesn't yet exist, you'll need to create it first by specifying a modeline:

```
$ xrandr --newmode <Mode``Line>
```

You may create a modeline using the gtf or cvt utility. For example, if you want to add a mode with resolution 800x600 at 60 Hz, you can enter the following command: (The output is shown following.)

```
$ cvt 800 600 60
# 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
```

Then copy the information after the word "Modeline" into the xrandr command:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
```

After the mode is entered, it needs to be added to the output using the --addmode command as explained above.

From: [X/Config/Resolution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions)

Comment: I get an error when trying to select the newly added configuration:
**The selected configuration for displays could not be applied**
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1920, 1080), minimum=(1280, 1024), maximum=(1280, 1024)