# Screen Resolution not displaying properly on eee pc

Tags: xrandr, display-resolution

After installation, everything works normally except for the very big icons on the screen. I checked the screen resolution and found out that it is very low, 1024x600.

I tried searching Ask Ubuntu and Google for answers and I found some but it doesn't work for me. I also tried running `xrandr` and create a modeline using `cvt`, but it always gets an error.

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 600, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 220mm x 129mm
   1024x600       60.0*+   65.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I also followed all the possible steps that I can find here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution
- [Ubuntu 14.04: Low screen resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479243/ubuntu-14-04-low-screen-resolution)

It's not only the icon size, but also the windows and their contents are even bigger. Relatively. Some opened windows (i.e system settings, unity tweak tool, etc) are extending to the other sides of the desktop. Making it such a pain to configure my settings or do other stuff in my desktop.

Comment: Your resolution is fine. The native resolution of the Asus EEE pc 1015px is 1024x600. What you seem to actually want to do is change the size of the icons.

Comment: It's not only the icon size, but also the windows and their contents are even bigger. Relatively. Some opened windows (i.e system settings, unity tweak tool, etc) are extending to the other sides of the desktop. Making it such a pain to configure my settings or do other stuff in my desktop.

Comment: Did the marked duplicate question solve your issue or what bain just mentioned?

Comment: @KaiSales Unity is being designed for high-resolution screens. Some of the default windows for settings etc. do open too big on low-resolution screens and can not be resized. These are bugs in Unity that only appear at low-res. I would suggest reporting these bugs on Launchpad, but the Unity designers do not seem to be so responsive to Launchpad bugs, so perhaps it would be better to raise the issue on the [unity-design mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~unity-design). Screenshots would be useful to make your case.